# Name of Exception thrown at Invalid login during Lists.asmx in SharePoint?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

what is the name of exception class which is being thrown when a client calls a web service with an invalid credentials in SharePoint.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

`UnauthorizedAccessException`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.unauthorizedaccessexception.aspx

Comment: +1 thanks, what other possible exceptions may at the client side? I'm already handling TimeoutException, SecurityException,SoapException, UnauthorizedAccessException and general Exception